# Como hacer un Post con una referencia en Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo el siguiente modelo relacionado con un Usuario

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ... 
    ...
```

Lo que me quiero hacer es crear un comentario de un Usuario, es decir un POST

Estos son mis Serializers

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
      model = Comment
      fields = '__all__'


class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
      view_name="comment-detail",
      read_only=True
  )
  comment = CommentSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['url', 'comment']


  def create(self, validated_data):
      comment_data = validated_data.pop('comment')
      # Aquí quiero traer el Usuario que esta hacuendio la petición
      # Referenciar el Usuario 
      # user 
      Comment.objects.create(user=user, **comment_data)
```

En las vistas estoy usando un viewset

```
class UserCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCommentSerializer
```

En la vista de Django Rest, solo me habilita la opción de Update no de un Post

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que "solo me habilita la opción de Update no de un Post"? ¿Cómo estás intentando hacer el post? En principio debería dejarte, ya que el post está incluído en el `ModelViewSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Si la pregunta es cómo pasarle el usuario que tiene la sesión iniciada al crear el comentario:

```
class UserCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCommentSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

El ejemplo lo puedes ver en la [documentación oficial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users).

Answer (score 0):

Recordemos que `ViewSet` tiene acciones y entre ellas no se encuentra como tal el post si no el `update`

```
def list(self, request):
    pass

def create(self, request):
    pass

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    pass

def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

Estas son las acciones que puedes realizar con tu `ViewSet`

Te dejo el link de la documentación oficial  -->
[Documentación ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset)